# Fatal error when deploy a clean install of Laravel app in 1and1 hosting

Tags: php, laravel-5, hosting

I'm trying to upload a Laravel application to a 1and1 hosting, but I'm facing some problems. This is what I get when I try to access to my app:

> Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '/homepages/39/d425938714/htdocs/webs/myapplication/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php' (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php5.6') in /homepages/39/d425938714/htdocs/webs/myapplication/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 12

It's a clean install of Laravel.

Thanks in advance.

Answering the comments:

@feela, yes, that path exists in the server.

@aynber, yes, I did `composer install` in my local machine, then I zipped the entire folder, uploaded to the server and unzipped the file.

Comment: Is this path (`/homepages/39/d425938714/htdocs/webs/myapplication/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php`) correct? Can you find that file on the server? I know 1&1 is not a good hoster, but this problem does not seem to be related to the hoster at all…

Comment: Have you run `composer install`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that when I unzip the the file, the names of the classes change to lower case, I don't know why, and that's why the application couldn't find any class. It was looking for `ClassLoader.php` when the class was renamed to `classLoader.php`.